# make two div diagnoal background design for invoice footer in mpdf in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, mpdf

want to create same design for invoice footer in mpdf
i have  already  tried almost hundred of code but not working in mpdf.

[image]

Does any other pdf library in php support css for this kind of design? Code example appreciated.

```
<style>
  .content {
     width: 100%;
          background-color: white;
         
        }

        .diagonal {
          border-top: 90px solid #243A53;
          border-right: 28px solid white;
          height: 0;
          width: 50%;
          display: inline-block;
          float: left;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0;
          top:-10%;
          z-index: -1;
        }
       

        .diagonal1 {
          border-bottom: 35px solid orange;
          border-left: 25px solid white;
          height: 0;
          width: 43%;
          display: inline-block;
          float: right;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0%;
          margin-top:52px;
          z-index: -1;

        }
<style>
<body>
 <div class="content" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0">
       <div class="diagonal" >
       </div>
       <div class="diagonal1" ></div>
   </div>
<body>
```